# Hide address bar of UiWebview when showing google maps on it

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios

i m showing map on UIWebView using this..

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f",
                                                latitudeValue,longitudeValue]];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[url release];

[web loadRequest:requestObj];
[web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollTo(0, 250);"];
```

but "`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`" not working.. please help me to solve this..
i want to hide address bar,and i know which is not a part of UiWebview ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to link directly to the Google Maps service, the page the iPhone users are shown when they visit maps.google.com. Instead, you should either use a MapView in your application or one of the Google Maps APIs, such as a static map.

Just to address your other issue, the execution of the Javascript, the problem is that the page needs to be loaded before the Javascript is executed. Assign a delegate to UIWebView and listen for *webViewDidFinishLoad* and then you can safely execute the javascript.